# In which order PCA components is printed? I need the parameters to solve pca formula. How do I know who the beta values are?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm using sklearn PCA technique. I need to solve:

```
pca1 =  beta1. c1 + beta2. c2 + beta3. c3 + beta4. c4 + beta5. c5
```

I read in the documentation that The components are sorted by explained_variance_. How do I know who the beta values are?

```
d = {'c1': [3, 7 ,1 ,4], 'c2': [8, 2 ,9 ,5], 'c3': [0, 7 ,9 ,2], 'c4': [3, 5 ,9 ,1], 'c5': [4, 6 ,8 ,3]}
data= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print("data:\n",data,"\n")
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
pca = PCA(n_components=1)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, columns = ['principal 
component 1'])
print("\ncomponents: \n",pca.components_,"\n")
print("\nexplained_variance_\n",pca.explained_variance_,"\n")
```

> Result:

data:

```
+--+----+----+----+-----+----+
|  | c1 | c2 | c3 |  c4 | c5 |
|0 |  3 |  8 |  0 |  3  | 4  |
|1 |  7 |  2 |  7 |  5  | 6  |
|2 |  1 |  9 |  9 |  9  | 8  |
|3 |  4 |  5 |  2 |  1  | 3  |
+--+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

components:

```
[[-0.32703417  0.29320425  0.45731291  0.55565347  0.53776765]]
```

explained_variance_:

```
[ 3.10207373]
```

Comment: I believe it is `data.dot(pca.components_.T)`

Comment: Do you know how I  get alpha value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beta are components!

beta1 = -0.32703417

beta2 = 0.29320425

beta3 = 0.45731291

beta4 = 0.55565347

beta5 = 0.53776765